# How do I change an image on image Mouse over in UWP

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

On Dashboard i have an image e.g - ManageUser.png. so on mouse over i want to change image(replace image to MnageUserBright.png) in UWP

```
<Image Source="manage_user.png" Height="120" Width="120"  Tapped="ManageUserPage"  Margin="176,31,534,84" Grid.Row="1"  />
```

i have just image code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `PointerEntered` event on that `<Image>` element so when the user moves their mouse pointer or finger over the image, you can trigger some code to replace the image:

`<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="manage_user.png" Height="120" Width="120"  Tapped="ManageUserPage"  Margin="176,31,534,84" Grid.Row="1" PointerEntered="OnPointerOverImage"  />`

```
public void OnPointerOverImage(Object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage("PathToYourNewImageFile", UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

When the user moves their pointer out of your image, you will need to do the opposite by handling the `PointerExited` event to set the original image back.

Answer (score 1):

Thank @Rafeal and I suggest that use all the xaml code to do it.

The first thing is installing a Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed. How to install see: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/

This way is using the Storyboard to change the Image source when the user mouse enter.

Define two storyboards.

```
       <Border.Resources>
           <Storyboard x:Key="EnterStoryboard">
               <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="assets/click_cursor_mouse_pointer_select_128px_1225441_easyicon.net.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
               </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
           </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ExitStoryboard">
               <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Assets/click_cursor_mouse_pointer_select_121.7433808554px_1193623_easyicon.net.png"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
               </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Border.Resources>
```

And put the image to the Border.

```
    <Border>
        <Border.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="EnterStoryboard">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                Value="manage_user.png" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ExitStoryboard">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                Value="Assets/normal.png" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Border.Resources>
        <Image x:Name="Image"
               Source="manage_user.png"
               Height="120" Width="120" Margin="176,31,534,84" />
    </Border>
```

Using the event trigger.

```
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource EnterStoryboard}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ExitStoryboard}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The code is all write in xaml. And you should replace the source.

```
<Grid>
    <Border>
        <Border.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="EnterStoryboard">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                Value="assets/click_cursor_mouse_pointer_select_128px_1225441_easyicon.net.png" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ExitStoryboard">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                Value="Assets/click_cursor_mouse_pointer_select_121.7433808554px_1193623_easyicon.net.png" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Border.Resources>
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource EnterStoryboard}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ExitStoryboard}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Image x:Name="Image"
               Source="Assets/click_cursor_mouse_pointer_select_121.7433808554px_1193623_easyicon.net.png"
               Height="120" Width="120" Margin="176,31,534,84" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The code in github https://github.com/lindexi/lindexi_gd/tree/7f0dcf62f38eda513b3455658b9dffd6c4974847/PernemtanowsearDeerawkurkosa